# Excel VBA Web Scraping not referencing created internet explorer object

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get some data from a website that requires inputting into forms. The code below is opening a new internet explorer window but then when it gets to the pointed out line Run-time error 462 comes up saying the remote server does not exist or is unavailable. Is the new window not being assigned to the ie object?

```
Sub Code()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim ht As HTMLDocument
    Dim result As String



    'Browser Initialization
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "url"

--->Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Loop

    Set ht = ie.document
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

It gives the same error at the set ht = ie.document line as well if I get rid if the loop.I am running on  Windows 10, is that the issue?

Comment: Does it actually navigate to the URL you give?

Comment: When the `Set ht` line runs is the browser window showing any content?  If you put a break on that line and wait a few seconds before continuing, does it work?

Comment: Yes it is navigating to the URL and showing the page, but when it gets to the Do loop it returns the error.

Comment: And yes in the case described the browser window is showing content

Comment: Remote server is not about the ie object. Likely you need to use InternetExplorerMedium and also verify url is correct. Security settings may be blocking.

Comment: Not about it being set I mean.